# Would redis ever hit loadavg of 4 in a four core machine?

Tags: redis

I am running a single instance of Redis in a 4 core machine. Is it correct to assume that the loadavg as seen via /proc/loadavg will be max 1 when the redis is at max capacity.

Max capacity defined as the max throughput that Redis can support.

This assumption stems from the fact that redis is single threaded and that the process will be attached to only one core.

Is there anything wrong with the assumption above? Will OS distribute the load to multiple cores in case one is loaded?

Comment: Recommend for general understanding of loadavg:
https://serverfault.com/questions/618130/proper-way-of-interpreting-system-load-on-a-4-core-8-thread-processor/618139

And here's a post about Redis 6 multi-core:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261077/can-redis-6-take-advantage-of-multi-core-cpus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with Redis maintainers. Redis is single threaded and will not hit a loadavg of 4 in a 4 core machine since that means that redis CPU is consuming CPU time from all the 4 cores which won't happen since the costly event loop operations happen on a single thread.